# sas sql pass-through to macro variable as a character

Tags: sql, casting, sas, pass-through

How to read macro variable as a character in SAS SQL pass-through

My goal is to put "one" as the only value in var3 , but now i get

"unknown column one"

```
 %macro test(notvar=)

proc sql;
      connect to odbc as conn (datasrc=x user=&user1. password=&pwd1.);
      create table &notvar. (compress=no) as select * from connection to conn
      (
            select var1, var2,
            &notvar. as var3
            from table1
      );
disconnect from conn;
quit;

%mend test;

%test(notvar=one);
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove all the macro references...and hard code all your parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested though. I think you can put the macro variable as value of column like:

```
 select var1, var2,
 "&notvar" as var3
 from table1
```

or

```
 select var1, var2,
 symget('notvar') as var3
 from table1
```

If no quotation mark or function for fetching macro variable value is specified, the selected object ("one" here in your case) is regarded as a column in the original table. So you get error for there is no such column.

Comment: the symget approach will throw an error in SQL passthrough, as that is a native SAS function..

Comment: @RawFocus It is fine in a macro setting.